# How many monochloro products including stereoisomers of the given compound are possible?

Tags: organic-chemistry, stereochemistry, hydrocarbons

[image]

I tried solving problems and I got 2 products.

[image]

However according to my book the answer is 3 products.

Comment: (II) has a stereoisomer. I also had to look twice, no sweat. ;)

Comment: Your second J molecule has got two stereoisomers, one (S) and one (R)